# Can we Create alert Dialog With Radiobuttons and Checkboxes in Blackberry

Tags: dialog, blackberry, alert

i want to `create a alert dialog with radiobuttons` for single selection `or` `alert dialog with Checkboxes` for Multiselection in blackberry.it is possible in android.but i want in blackberry.i searched in google.but i didn't got any solution.please give any suggestions r usefull links for this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import net.rim.device.api.system.Bitmap;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.CheckboxField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.Dialog;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.DialogFieldManager;

public class CheckboxInputDialog extends Dialog{

  private CheckboxField checkboxEditField;

  public CheckboxInputDialog(String choices[],int values[], String label){
    super(label, choices,values,Dialog.OK, Bitmap.getPredefinedBitmap(Bitmap.INFORMATION), Dialog.GLOBAL_STATUS);

    checkboxEditField  = new CheckboxField("Lablel",false);
    net.rim.device.api.ui.Manager delegate = getDelegate();
    if( delegate instanceof DialogFieldManager){
        DialogFieldManager dfm = (DialogFieldManager)delegate;
        net.rim.device.api.ui.Manager manager =dfm.getCustomManager();
        if( manager != null ){
            manager.insert(checkboxEditField, 0);
        }
    }

 }    

}
```

Now Call this dialog at following way...

```
    String choices[] = { "OK", "CANCEL" };
    int values[] = { Dialog.OK, Dialog.CANCEL };
    CheckboxInputDialog d = new CheckboxInputDialog(choices,values,"Dialog Label");
    d.show();
```

Output will Be:

[image]

Get Event of OK and Cancel Button.

```
String choices[] = { "OK", "CANCEL" };
    int values[] = { Dialog.OK, Dialog.CANCEL };
    final CheckboxInputDialog d = new CheckboxInputDialog(choices, values,"Dialog Label");
    UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            int iResponse = d.doModal();
            if (iResponse == 0) {
                System.out.println("Press Ok");
            }else{
                System.out.println("Press Cancel");
            }
        }
    });
```

Hope Help full..

Comment: Thank u.but i have some doubts regarding this.i want to perform some action on button ok.how i have to write that

Answer (score 0):

Create popupScreen and in this screen you can add radiobuttons and Checkboxes.

```
public class Custom_Popup extends PopupScreen {

public Custom_Popup() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    super( new VerticalFieldManager(Manager.VERTICAL_SCROLL),
Field.NON_FOCUSABLE | Field.USE_ALL_WIDTH );



}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

On your event, push this screen.

```
UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new MyPopup());


public class MyPopup extends PopupScreen{
public MyPopup() {
    super(new VerticalFieldManager(), Field.FOCUSABLE);
    add();//add checkbox , radio buttons here.
}
```